# Suddenly Batch file is not recognized in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have below structure in my Jenkins slave machine

Batch File-->YML file-->Jmeter Script

When I execute a script through Jenkins, it first call the batch file on my windows machine which in turn call .yml file and lastly the .yml file calls the Jmeter script.This scenario was working fine from past 2-3 years but from last few days I am getting below error in Jenkins

'abc.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I do not know what happened. I did not changed anything on my slave machine.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance,
Jatin

Comment: are you running it in on master or slave? Which os is it? Please post your entire output.

Comment: I have one Jenkins Server where I do not have access. Within that Jenkis my Windows 7 machine is added as a slave. On that Slave I have all the scripts. On the Slave machine I executed abc.bat and it worked fine but when I execute it through Jenkins it did not worked.And  the mentioned error is what I am getting. "'abc.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Without pasting the entire output it would be very difficult to help you

Comment: Sorry cannot paste all of the data as it belongs to client.